# hibernate criteriaBuilder - how to achieve a "where in" subquery with no foreign key

Tags: hibernate, criteria-api

I have 2 entites...

```
@Entity
public class Thing1 {
  @Column
  long id;

  @Column
  String someReference
}

@Entity
public class Thing2 {
  @EmbeddedId
  Thing2PK id;

  @Embeddable
  public static class Thing2PK implements Serializable
  {
    @Column
    private String name;

        @Column(name = "client_id")
        private String account;

        @Column
        String possibleReference
    }
}
```

How do I use criteriaBuilder to build the following query...

```
SELECT *
FROM thing1
WHERE someReference IN (
 SELECT possibleReference 
 FROM thing2
 WHERE name = :name)
```

I was looking at `criteriaBuilder.in` but that requires either a set of values or a query that uses a `@JoinColumn` which, in this case, is not possible.

Comment: There are tons of tutorials on this topic. Just type in "jpa criteria subquery" on Google and you will find article like this for example: https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-subquery-criteriaquery/

Comment: Already tried. Requires a JoinColumn.

Answer (score 0):

> Already tried. Requires a JoinColumn.

I don't see a join column in the example I posted. Compare the solution to the article I posted and you will figure out that it is very similar. The below is just adapted to your model.

```java
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Thing1> cq = cb.createQuery(Thing1.class);
Root<Thing1> root = cq.from(Thing1.class);
ParameterExpression<String> param = cb.parameter(String.class);
 
Subquery<String> sub = cq.subquery(String.class);
Root<Thing2> subRoot = sub.from(Thing2.class);
sub.select(subRoot.get("id").get("possibleReference"));
sub.where(cb.equal(subRoot.get("id").get("name"), param));
 
cq.where(cb.in(root.get("someReference"), sub));
 
TypedQuery<Thing1> query = em.createQuery(cq);
query.setParameter(param, "THE NAME");
List<Thing1> results = query.getResultList();
```